# How to get the image from in memory cache using SDWebImage?

Tags: ios, objective-c, caching, sdwebimage

I have implemented SDWebImage in cellforrowatindexpath method. The problem here is when i scroll down the tableview the images are loading from web which is expected but when i scroll up the tableview the images are again downloading. What is the way to get rid of this problem. I don't want to load images from url overtime (since there is a usage limit with the web service call). I chose to use SDWebImage API for in memory cache so that once the images are loaded they are taken from cache to show it on the UI instead of making the web service call everytime. Here is my code:

```
[cell.placeImage sd_setImageWithURL:url placeholderImage:nil options:SDWebImageCacheMemoryOnly];
```

The above line is the only code in that method. Please help me.
Any kind of help is appreciated. I have seen other questions in this community but nobody said how to get an image from the cache memory.

Comment: just use `[cell.placeImage sd_setImageWithURL:url placeholderImage:nil]`

Comment: so do you mean i have to use the same line of code?

Comment: yes, but no need to use options...

Comment: @FahimParkar one more thing I got stuck that how to check a precondition I mean what is the line of code to say that if(image is there in cache) pull image from the cache this is where I will put your line code and in else statement I will put the line of code which I proposed this question. Do you have any idea what should be there in if statement? Well, I am trying to write this code in cellforrowatindexpath.

Comment: just write the statement I said, it handle automatically... it check if it is there locally, it show local image else it download the image locally and then show it...

Answer (score 1):

For refreshing of the images you should use option : `SDWebImageRefreshCached`

```
[imageView sd_setImageWithURL:url placeholderImage:nil options:SDWebImageRefreshCached];
```

Comment: as far as now I am just in the beginning where I have stucked to put a condition  to pull the image from cache and if it is not in cache then i need to make a network request.